# Am I Stuck With My AppDelegate's Deprecation Warnings?

Tags: ios

I am using Xcode 8, swift 3, targeting iOS 10.2

The declaration of the UIApplicationDelegate method called in response to notification registrations is:

```
optional func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegister notificationSettings: UIUserNotificationSettings)
```

However, UIUserNotificationSettings has been deprecated in iOS 10. Therefore, my AppDelegate class is producing a deprecation warning.

If my understanding is correct then I am stuck with this warning until Apple updates the definition of UIApplicationDelegate. However, this feels odd to me. So, I am posting this question in order to confirm my understanding.

Comment: You can just delete the method if you aren't using it.  If you are using it you should update your app to use the `UserNotifications` framework instead.

Comment: @dan Thanks for your response. How should I define the application:didRegister method in my AppDelegate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As 'dan' said, you should update to the new framework.

Head over to Apple's `Local and Remote Notification Programming Guide` here: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/

You'll find the specifics for Registering for notifications in AppDelegate on the 4th page (but read it all, so it's clear).

Comment: I quickly scanned the doc. I think that I get it now. If I use the UserNotification framework then I will not need the application:didRegister method and can thus remove it (and the warning). Is that correct?

Comment: Sort of... if your app *is* using Notifications, you will *replace* `application:didRegister` method with `application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken`